# Continuous communication between spring-boot and a single client

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, websocket

I have build this application using spring-boot and google app engine for the backend and a angular frontend. I want to implement some kind of functionality that enables a single client to send a request that is received by a spring controller. In that controller I want to do some computing and continuously send information to the client and receive information from the client.

Here is som pseudo-code of what I would like to do

```
@GetMapping("/compute")  
public String compute() {
    while (computing) {
        // compute something 
        // send that to client
        // receive response from client 
        // depending on response send something else to client
    }

    return "Finished"
}
```

I've read up some on websockets but as I haven't used them before I don't really know where to find information about my case.

Comment: *"I haven't used [websockets] before"* Well, now is a great time to **learn**. How about you set up your Spring webapp with support for WebSockets, and try it out? This is not a teaching site. Please don't ask us to teach you.

Comment: your question lacks details. You can use either a Websocket or server sent events

Comment: *FYI:* Your pseudo-code won't work, because each incoming message from the client is a new invocation of a `@MessageMapping` annotated Controller method. For this. you'll also need to learn how to write asynchronous logic. Much better for server resources than using synchronous logic like that pseudo-code.

Comment: I realise that the pseudo-code won't work, I just used it to clarify what I want to achieve. I'm not asking you to teach me, just to point at relevant frameworks and techniques which I then will look up more about and implement. It's the  _"new invocation of a @MessageMapping"_ that buggs me. Is there any way to have a continuous two-way communication with the client **within** a controller. Everything I've looked at about websockets I can't seem to figure out how to achieve what I want with websockets @Andreas

Comment: But you don't (shouldn't) want a continuous two-way communication with the client **within** a controller. What would the controller be doing between "send that to client" and "receive response from client"? Nothing. So after the "send to client", the controller method should return, and release the thread for use by other clients. When the client eventually responds, the `@MessageMapping` method is called and you can continue with your logic. You can save any needed state in the session, or in a file or database. It's **asynchronous** logic, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Okej I see! I understand why continuous two-way communication within a controller is not optimal now. My problem is that the computation I'm doing, if saved in the session and then continued would increase the complexity greatly and just waiting for the input is more effective. What would you recommend in this case? Is there a good way around this that is not rethinking the computation? I'm just weighing my options. Thanks for the help! @Andreas

Comment: I would strongly recommend refactoring the code for asynchronous execution. If you cannot / will not do that, I guess you could have your logic running in a background thread, and use a concurrent `Queue` or some such for your logic, to sit there and wait on response from client, and then have controller handler send response to the queue.

Comment: Okej in that case I will prioritise implementing asynchronous execution of the code if possible. I appreciate the help! Thanks! @Andreas